# SSD temp with conky

Tags: scripts, ssd, conky

I have a problem with conky.
I installed hddtemp and my ssd is shown like this:

```
/dev/sda: Crucial_CT120M500SSD1: 39°C
```

now in conky I wrote:

```
${alignr 10}${color}SSD M500 Crucial 120GB Temp ${color1}${hddtemp /dev/sda}ºC
```

But desktop shows N/A°C.

How can I fix it?
Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to have `hddtemp` running in daemon mode all the time, you could also run `hddtemp` as an external command instead. However, `hddtemp` needs to be run as root:

```
$ hddtemp /dev/sda
/dev/sda: open: Permission denied
$ sudo hddtemp /dev/sda
/dev/sda: ST3500418AS: 35°C
```

So, you will first need to give your user permission to run the command. Run `visudo` and add this line to the `sudoers` file (change `linofex` to your actual username):

```
linofex  ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/hddtemp
```

That should let you run `sudo hddtemp` without needing to enter a password.

Now, replace the line from your `conkyrc` file with:

```
${alignr 10}${color}SSD M500 Crucial 120GB Temp ${color1}${exec sudo hddtemp /dev/sda | awk '{print $NF}'}
```

Comment: I update sudoers file with the command, and now I can run hddtemp without password. But with the command conky doesn't show me the temp.

Comment: @linofex did you use `${exec sudo hddtemp /dev/sda | awk '{print $NF}'}`? If so, what does it show now?

Comment: SSD M500 Crucial 120GB Temp °C

Comment: @linofex and what command did you run in the `exec`? Not mine since I don't have a `°C ` there. Show me the exact command you ran and also try with `${exec sudo /usr/sbin/hddtemp /dev/sda | awk '{print $NF}'}`.

Comment: `${alignr 10}${color}SSD M500 Crucial 120GB Temp ${color1}${exec sudo hddtemp /dev/sda | awk '{print $NF}' }` show SSD M500 Crucial 120GB Temp

`${exec sudo /usr/sbin/hddtemp /dev/sda | awk '{print $NF}'}` doesn't show nothing

Comment: @linofex that's very strange. It works fine on my system. What does running `sudo hddtemp /dev/sda | awk '{print $NF}'` on the terminal return? Feel free to ping me in [chat] so we can debug this if you like.

Comment: this command on terminal show the temp! Yes, I'd lie solve this problem

Comment: Hi,  I reinstalled the distro and now with your guide I finally solved my problem! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

You need to first start hddtemp as a background daemon with the commmand:

```
 hddtemp -d /dev/sda
```

`${hddtemp ...}` is a conky built-in object. It connects to 127.0.0.1:7634
by default to get the disk temperatures. You therefore need to start, independently, the hddtemp daemon which listens on this port and replies with
the information.

An alternative is to use `${exec hddtemp /dev/sda}` which runs hddtemp 
on each window update, and does not need a daemon.

---

If you just want the temperature, pipe the output into awk to
get the next-to-last field (in my case) ie $(NF-1), or the last field
$NF in your case:

```
${exec hddtemp /dev/sda|awk '{print $NF}'}
```

Comment: what dose -d mean? (-daemon?)

Comment: yes. see `man hddtemp`.

Comment: If I run this command ' ${exec hddtemp /dev/sda} ' conky shows me all the information and not just the temp. How can I edit the command?

Comment: @linofex like terdon says, pipe the output through awk to select just the last field .

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to permit hddtemp with:

```
sudo chmod +s /usr/sbin/hddtemp
```

Then (based on your example), in your conkyrc file the item will become:

```
${execi 1 hddtemp /dev/sda|sed 's%/dev/sda: %%' }
```

This will give you just `Crucial_CT120M500SSD1: 39°C`.